# Guest account unable to login when graphic logon disabled

Tags: windows, login, user-accounts, windows-10, guest

I have disabled graphic logon on my Windows 10 Pro PC so that users have to type in their username when logging on. This throws up an error when I try and log in on the guest account, though:

> The sign in method you're trying to use isn't allowed. For more info, contact your network administrator.

It works on the default and administrator accounts perfectly well. How do I fix the guest account so they can login?

Comment: If you temporarily re-enable graphic login does guest work again?

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in as the administrator and opening an elevated command prompt (right click on command prompt icon and select run as administrator).
Then type:

```
net user guest /active:yes
```

Then see if it works.

If that doesn't help then check whether temporarily re-enabling graphic login makes the guest account work again?

Comment: It works if you enable graphic logon, but still shows the error if you change it back.

Comment: And that was after doing `net user guest /active:yes` ?

Comment: Yes I did that command